# Get list of optional props of a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to get the keys for any `propTypes` that reference an optional property (i.e are not specified as being required)?

For example, given the following props:

```
TestComponent.propTypes = {
    requiredProp: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    optionalProp: PropTypes.func,
    optionalProp2: PropTypes.element
}
```

...can I get an array that contains the items: `["optionalProp", "optionalProp2"]`

If there's no built-in way to do this, is there an elegant solution that:

1. Avoids hard-coding a list of them
2. Avoids deriving from a custom class with this functionality implemented
3. Can be used throughout all my react components

I was thinking of using the context to define such a function, and then call it on the current component like so: `this.context.getOptionalProps.call(this)`

But it seems like a bad use of the context.

Comment: Are you using `react@15` `PropTypes` or the new [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package? You can access PropTypes via `this.constructor.propTypes` but matching this against the `isRequired` properties might prove difficult

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I'm using the new `prop-types` package, if that's any help

Answer (score 3):

#### Update: solution below only works for `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'` use with caution or don't use

Not thoroughly tested, but I managed to filter out the prop keys that are required, and get an array of optional props like this:

```js
  /**
   * Given a PropTypes Object returns an array of optional
   * prop keys.
   *
   * @param propTypes
   */
  const optionalProps = propTypes => Object.keys(propTypes).filter(k => propTypes[k].isRequired);

  // console.log(optionalProps(TestComponent.PropTypes) output:
  // Array [
  //   "optionalProp",
  //   "optionalProp2",
  // ]
```

Then just export it and import for use wherever in your React application.

Comment: Does his work? I'm pretty sure it doesn't for the prop-types package at least because isRequired returns a function

Comment: I tried it with the `prop-types` package and it seemed to be working. Granted it's not thoroughly tested, I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: It just returned all properties for me, regardless of isRequired. See this [RunKit example](https://runkit.com/ryan-codingintrigue/59ddf91cddac850012ec640d)

Comment: Ah, looks like it works when `NODE_ENV !== 'production'`, which explains why it worked for me. See this [RunKit example](https://runkit.com/janneklouman/prop-types-dev).